# To stop Java handler

Tags: android, handler

I have a Java handler code which Im using in android to run a Timer...It runs awesome.

I need help to stop this timer(Handler) programmatically...Any simple method to stop this handler,when I exit from the activity in Android???

The Handler code section is :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() 
    {
        // Do something after duration
    }
}, duration);
```

How to stop this handler , so that the statement should not be executed after duration time. Or is there any other way to use a delay timer thread which can be handled by ourself???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep references to your Runnables, then call `removeCallbacks(runnable)` on for each Runnable you've added to your handler to remove them.

Comment: Can u please give me a link or example,on how to implement the above removeCallbacks(runnable)???